# submit two values from two different dropdown list in php

Tags: php, html, css

I have a function having two dropdown list and one submit button, the user must choose a value from dropdown list A and a value from dropdown list B so he can submit them.

I knew that I need to have an attribute in the value section as follows

```
<select name="students" id="students">
<?php 
while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($selectstudent1)) {
$name=$data['name'];
$idname =$data['user_id_student'];
?>
<option name="studentdd" value="<?php echo $idname; ?>"><?php 
echo $name; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

and the second dropdown list here

```
<select name="groups" id="groups">
<?php
while($data1 = mysqli_fetch_array($selectgroup1)) {
$groupschoose = $data1['group_number']; ?>
<option name="nogroup" value="<?php echo $groupschoose; ?>">
<?php echo $groupschoose; ?></option>
<?php }//while ?>
</select>
```

so, i need to get the "php echo $idname" (student id) from A dropdown list
and "php echo $groupschoose; " (group id) form drop downlist B
so I tried this PHP code as follows:

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['addmember'])){ 
//addmember is id for dropdownlists form
$groupnum= $_POST['nogroup'];
$stuid=$_POST['studentdd'];
echo $groupnum;
echo $stuid ;

$sq="SELECT user_id_student FROM student WHERE 
user_id_student=$stuid ";

$sq1 = mysqli_query($con,$sq);
while ($sq2 = mysqli_fetch_array($sq1)) {
$tes = $sq2['user_id_student'];
if( $tes == $stuid){


$sqlmem="UPDATE student
set group_id= $groupnum
WHERE user_id_student=$stuid";
$resultmem = mysqli_query($con,$sqlmem);}
}

}
?>
```

But it won't work, and I'm not sure where is the missing section
I hope my Q is clear and I'm sorry if it's little bit long, but i'm looking for your help, thank you!!

Comment: You only give the `select` element the `name` attribute, not the `option` elements.  Then you use the name of the `select` elements as the index in the PHP code.

Comment: Thankyou it worked well !!, but I need to click submit two times, why?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean.  If your elements are in the same form, and you only have one submit button, they will both be submitted when you submit the form.  To be honest, it is hard to understand exactly what it is you _want_ to achieve, and what is currently happening.

Comment: well I'm sorry if it's not clear, what I mean is not the function not working, it works, but like I need to submit first time nothing happen, the second time it goes well, but anyway I'm very thankful, thank you for your time